# Teaspoons of Vinegar to Gallon.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to regulate my ponds PH level, but I'm having trouble on the teaspoon conversion. Vinegar is supposed to lower my PH level so I need to put vinegar in my water, but how much?

1/4 Vinegar = 1/2 Gallon of Water
My pond has 4000 Gallons of Water
1/2 = 1 gallon

1tsp = 2000 Gallons?

48 tsp in 1 cup
48cups = 2000
2000 / 48 = 41.7 Cups of Vinegar to go into a 4000 gallon pond.

Does this sounds right?

**EDIT** I had no idea what tags to put if somebody could retag this that would be amazing.

Comment: In the first line, you have $1/4$ vinegar $=$ $1/2$ gallon of water.  It is $1/4$ what? Maybe $1/4$ teaspoon? Or is it $1/4$ cup? One needs to specify.

Comment: If it is $1/4$ teaspoon, then your calculation is correct.

Comment: Yeah it's 1/4 teaspoon

Answer (score 1):

6 teaspoons = 1 fluid ounce, so there are 128*6 = 768 teaspoons to the gallon.  At this point it's a chemistry calculation.  You must test the pH of the water and the pH of the vinegar solution you add.  To do this you need a pH meter or pH test tape.   The water is likely not neutral.